# How can I split string into groups using regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to split the string 'A123456789123B' into six groups using the following regular expression:

```
'/^([A-Z]{1})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([A-Z]{1})$/'
```

I tried using:

```
preg_split('/^([A-Z]{1})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([A-Z]{1})$/', 'A123456789123B');
```

However, it does not work.

I need to split the string into something like this:

```
['A', '123', '456', '789', '123', 'B']
```

Comment: Is number of characters in each block fixed?

Comment: Would have thought of preg_split with reset: [`(?:^.|...)\K`](https://regex101.com/r/lD1vI7/1) but this interestingly gives [different results in different php versions](https://3v4l.org/aJ0nT).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be better suited to use [`preg_match()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) for this:

```
preg_match('/^([A-Z]{1})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})([A-Z]{1})$/', 'A123456789123B', $matches);
array_shift($matches);
```

Your array of matches will be stored in `$matches`. The first element of `$matches` will contain the whole string matched, and the remaining elements will be the specific capturing groups in the parentheses. We use [`array_shift()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) to remove the first element.

Here's an example:

```
php > var_dump(preg_match('/^([A-Z]{1})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})([A-Z]{1})$/', 'A123456789123B', $matches));
int(1)
php > var_dump($matches);
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "A123456789123B"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "A"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "123"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "456"
  [4]=>
  string(3) "789"
  [5]=>
  string(3) "123"
  [6]=>
  string(1) "B"
}
php > array_shift($matches);
php > var_dump($matches);
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "A"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "123"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "456"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "789"
  [4]=>
  string(3) "123"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "B"
}
php >
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you should rather use preg_match cause split will search for a separator and you have none here :

```
$str = 'A123456789123B';
preg_match('/^([A-Z]{1})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([A-Z]{1})$/', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Then you'll have to remove the first key of $matches :

```
if ($matches) {
    array_shift($matches)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`preg_split()` is perfectly suited to directly providing the desired result.

Match the first character in the string or three consecutive characters, the release the matched characters with `\K` so that no characters are lost in the explosion.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/4eVAP))

```
$str = "A123456789123B";

var_export(
    preg_split('/(?:^.|...)\K/', $str)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'A',
  1 => '123',
  2 => '456',
  3 => '789',
  4 => '123',
  5 => 'B',
)
```